# comparsions between limesurvey and wufoo-like service

Tags: wufoo, limesurvey

limesurvey is good enough and it is open-source, but why are wufoo-like services so popular nowadays?

Wufoo has a much more fancy user interface than limesurvey but why does limesurvey not make some improvements(2.0??)?

For business solution, which will be preferred in general case?

Answer (score 3):

For one, I think the fact that the UI is so slick is one of the BIG reasons why services like Wufoo are indeed so popular.  The target audience of these services is generally non-developer types who use mostly point-and-click interfaces and are very visual with their work, so a clean, well-organized UI that lends itself to ease of use will always win out.

After briefly testing both Wufoo and LimeSurvey, the difference in usage of drag-and-drop (Wufoo) vs. traditional text box and dropdown (Limesurvey) is readily apparent.  While I felt overwhelmed at the start of both services, I did feel that Wufoo at least had some hints on which direction to go next if I was stuck, and never had a ton of controls on the page for me to see.  It actually felt like a WYSIWYG editor for forms/surveys.

LimeSurvey on the other hand does not feel like it has any flow, and it's incredibly easy to get a bunch of toolbars on-screen that further confuse me.  I can't speak to how comparable it is to Wufoo, or how powerful it is, but I have a feeling that while it can probably match what Wufoo can produce in terms of surveys, it probably requires much more expertise on my part.

But these are just my observations as a developer who has just recently heard of and tried both services.